# Use of まで in this sentence

Tags: grammar

The sentence is 出口が無けりゃ作るまでよ.

I'm pretty sure it means something along the lines of "If there is not a door, just make one"
It confuses me because 出口が無けりゃ should mean "If there is not a door" and 作るまでよ should mean "until you make it".

Please tell me your translation and explain how まで is used in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/208999/m1u/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7/

> ３ 動作・事柄がもうそれ以上には及ばず、それに限られる意を表す。…だけ。
>
> 「気に入らなければ断るまでさ」
>   「念のために聞いてみたまでだ」

should be able to see how it's used from those two examples.

Translation: If there's no way out then all you need to do is make one.