# What does the phrase 「ところまでいくまで」 mean?

Tags: words

I have came across the phrase from the below sentence.

いきつく**ところまでいくまで**だ。

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21235/7810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`いきつくところ` <- The ultimate state / where it ultimately leads to / the end state

> もうこの会社にはお金がないが、いきつくところ(Bankruptcy, acquisition etc., whatever the end may be)までいきたい。

`〜までだ` <- Determination to do something undesirable in order to achieve something (the literal meaning is `we merely need to do X`)

> 電車がもうないなら、歩いて帰るまでだ

So the literal meaning is `I will merely see this to the end`, and what is implied is `Whatever the outcome may be, I shall persist and see this to the end`